# Errors compling sample source code from open-gltutorial.org

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glfw, visual-studio-2010

I've tried and tried to compile source from the site listed. Specifically the second one involving a triangle. So here's a list of my lib includes:

```
opengl32.lib
glfw3.lib
glu32.lib
glfw3dll.lib
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
freeglut.lib
```

I'm on windows 7 x64, IDE is VS2010 express C++ registered, all my includes and libs are for x86, here are my errors. I did get CMake to make the project files for me and then I got the tutorials to build too.

```
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__TrackMouseEvent@4
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DispatchMessageW@4
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PeekMessageW@20
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetMessageTime@0
```

There's like 50 more like that too. They all start with the glfw3.lib too. Makes me think I didn't have the right library files there but I've tried every lib file I've got, tried the binarys prebuilt for windows and everything. The includes for the project file from the tutorial websites are as follows:

```
// these are already included by VS 2010.

kernel32.lib //
user32.lib//
gdi32.lib//
winspool.lib//
shell32.lib//
ole32.lib//
oleaut32.lib//
uuid.lib//
comdlg32.lib//
advapi32.lib//

glu32.lib
opengl32.lib
external\glfw-3.0.3\src\Release\glfw3.lib
external\Release\GLEW_190.lib
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise including both the dynamic and static version of each lib.

Comment: How do I tell the difference? Is it in the naming or what?

Comment: It depends where you got them from, but the naming usually gives it away; ones with 's' at the end (i.e. glew32s) are usually static. Another thing to check is, are you getting any errors like "failed to open file foo.lib"? And have you given VS the correct directories to find these libraries you're trying to link to? That could cause this issue.

Comment: No, no such errors, it's opening the files and then something goes wrong. I'll try to make the files from the glfw website again, not the ones I got from the tutorial website.

Comment: For simplicity sake, try it to work with just the static versions of the libraries first. I currently have a project that uses glfw and have the following libraries linked: 'glfw3.lib;opengl32.lib;glew32s.lib'. You might also want to check you're not trying to build a 32 bit application with 64 bit libraries and vice versa.

Comment: I've rebuilt glfw in a new dir, included and linked, made sure they were 32bit and unlinked glfw3dll.lib, then changed to the static glew32s.lib, and unliked glew32.lib. Still no dice.

Comment: When you say included, have you added the directory for the libs under VC++ Directories, or just the headers?

Comment: I included the header files and linked the lib files. It's a really simple one file .cpp so the headers are under #include's and the .libs are linked through the project config.

Comment: What I mean is, does VS know where to look for the libs? You need to add it to the linker directories.

Comment: Yes, when I say I'm linking the libraries, I'm including the path to the .lib files as well. All I did was to copy and paste the .libs to the library folder under the program files, into there respective directories. I'm getting the same error across multiple IDE's. I'm pretty sure I've done everything right. All the files are for 32bit, I'm compiling for 32bit, the libs are linked and the dir's are correct, the includes are included and dir's on them correct. This is not my first rodeo linking files to the linker.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/OMGtechy/DDGL as it links GLFW3 correctly, and look for differences. It uses VS 2013 so you'd be est getting the express edition of that, however you can just use a text editor to view the project files.

Comment: I've delinked the static libs and linked the dynamic ie glew32.lib and glfw3dll, I was down to this error: 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShaders(char const *,char const *)" (?LoadShaders@@YAIPBD0@Z)
then I added shader.cpp to my project and it now builds without build errors but now I have an error in the CLI window stating impossible to get simplevertexshader.vertexshader, are you in the right directory? Not sure why the statics didn't work for my source. New list of unfound dll errors when the program runs I quit it.triangle also never shows

Comment: Check you have the dlls copied into the right place :-)

Comment: You mean to the windows\SYSWOW64 and windows\system32 folders? I put the supplied dll's into those folders long ago. I'm using VS2013 express now but it doesn't work when I try to include shaders and the code for the triangle, the window code works just fine until the second tutorial.

Comment: No, in the directory where you project is. You shouldn't be putting anything in system32. Try next to the exe that is generated, or by the project file.

Comment: Oh gotcha, that does make sense. Hopefully people with my linking problems can figure it out from all this. Still no clue why the source works with dynamic libs and not the statics though.

Comment: Did you forget to undefine glfw_dynamic (or whatever it is) when linking the static libs?

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure what I've done because I've got glfw3.lib linked and they say that the 3 means it's static... I figure that it was a PEBKAC error wrapped in an I-D-10t error :P Stressful week even without this problem. Thanks for hanging on with me there techy. Now that it's working for me I'll be able to learn openGL and all the other related libraries.

Comment: The 3 does not mean it is static, it is a version number. Glad to help, so is this sorted now? If so I will write it up and post it as an answer.